# Is $f(x) =x^{-1}$ an analytic function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

As a *prospective* undergraduate who is doing pre-study in preparation for my future endeavours, i recently learnt about analytic functions and would like to know whether $f(x) = x^{-1}$ is analytic in the domain of $x$ ?

My attempt: since $\dfrac{f^{(n)}}{n!}x = -(n-1)!x^{-n-1}$ is undefined at $x=0$, we can't have a Laurent series for $f$, hence not analytic ?

What am not sure of is that, since $x=0$ doesn't exist in the domain of $x$, is this argument valid ?

Comment: You are confusing concepts: $x^{-1}$ *is* it's own [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) about $x=0$, but to be analytic at a point $f$ is required to have a convergent *power series* in some disc about that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the reciprocal function is analytic *throughout its domain*, i.e., admits a convergent power series expansion around each non-zero number: If $a \neq 0$, the geometric series formula gives
$$
\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{a\bigl[1 + (x - a)/a\bigr]}
  = \frac{1}{a} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left[-\frac{(x - a)}{a}\right]^{k}\qquad \text{for $|x| < a$}. 
$$
(The same argument works whether you mean real-analytic or complex-analytic.)

Comment: Thank you very much, Andrew !, that really helped !

Comment: The condition of applicability should read "$|x - a| < a$" instead of "$|x| < a$", of course....

Answer (score 2):

The domain of the function $f(x)=x^{-1}$ is $\mathbb{R}-0$, so the question is whether this function is analytic at a values $x=a$ which is nonzero. And yes it is, because its Taylor series centered on $x=a$ is equal to
$$\frac{1}{a} \biggl( 1 - \frac{x-a}{a} + \frac{(x-a)^2}{a^2} - \frac{(x-a)^3}{a^3} \pm \cdots \biggr)
$$
which has radius of convergence $|a|$ and whose limit equals $f(x)$ on the interval of convergence $(a-a,a+a)=(0,2a)$ (when $a$ is positive).

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, Lee !